How to specify parameter type as derived class type in override of abstract function where parameter is type of base class?
I would like to store SpecificResult instances (and other types derived from Result) in a List<Result>. Each derived type may contain different properties. I would like to have a virtual base class method LimitsPassed on Result that checks if those specific properties meet some criteria (e.g. values of properties from the Limits derived instances that are passed as parameter to the method). Different classes derived from Results should receive different types of Limits.
I've tried to override the LimitsPassed method with a more-derived SpecificLimits parameter.
Obviously the code shown here doesn't compile, because type in derived class does not match base class definition.
What are possible solutions for that?
public abstract class Result
{
    public abstract bool LimitsPassed(Limits limits)
}

public class SpecificResult : Result
{
    public double MeasureA { get; set; }
    public string MeasureB { get; set; }

    public override bool LimitsPassed(SpecificLimits limits) 
    {
        //specify parameter base type to particular type of derived class

        return this.MeasureA >= limits.MeasureA_min
                && this.MeasureA <= limits.MeasureA_max
                && this.MeasureB == limits.MeasureB_master;
    }
}

public abstract class Limits
{
}

public class SpecificLimits : Limits
{
    public double MeasureA_min { get; set; }
    public double MeasureA_max { get; set; }

    public string MeasureB_master { get; set; }
}


Sounds like your Result class probably needs to be generic in the type of limit it can receive. (e.g. class Result<TLimit> where TLimit : Limits). Then SpecificResult : Result<SpecificLimits>...

If I may challenge your design a little bit... What happens when you call LimitsPassed on a SpecificResult and provide Limits which are not SpecificLimits?  Part of the the job of a SpecificResult (by virtue of the fact that is is a Result) is that it must provide an implementation of LimitsPassed(Limits)  What's the relationship between SpecificResult and SpecificLimits?  In other words, why does SpecificResult care what kind of Limits it is passed given that is is a Result?

@Wyck I would like to store SpecificResults (and other types dervied from Results) in a List. Each derived type may contain different properties. Method LimitsPassed should check if those properties meets some criteria (f.e. limits). Different classes derived from Results will have different properties and should recieve different types of limits. And finally LimitsPassed implements logic to check if properties meets requirements.

In terms of design smell, it does not sound like a SpecificLimits is a Limits because you say that "Different classes derived from Results will have different properties".  I'm saying, perhaps LimitsPassed(Limits limits) should not be a member of Result.  Your question should provide some kind of motivation for why all Results should be able to do LimitsPassed on an arbitrary Limits.  I ask because I'm trying to determine if public new bool LimitsPassed(SpecificLimits limits) is what you need (to hide the base class method, but still provide an implementation)

@Wyck, I editet my question and added some implementation of classes. I created classes Results and Limits, because I would like to call method LimitsPassed with parameter of base class and let the program decide what is exact derived type on runtime. I also tried with extension methods, but I cannot call them on base class also.

This question is similar to: Is it possible to override a method with a derived parameter instead of a base one?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Think about or tell us how you want to use that. If your code surrounds a List you would presumably mostly know that it is a Result and have a hard time using a more specific version of the base method without constantly knowing/checking/casting to the derived class of Result.

From the comments and your question I don't see anything that is really common to Limits, so maybe we can have a base Result class that looks like this (I've made LimitsPassed return null instead of throwing exceptions for invalid limit types but that's a matter of choice of course)
public abstract class Result {
    // can be bool but then we have to throw exceptions
    // when invalid Limits type
    public abstract bool? LimitsPassed(object limits);

    // helps us when we have List<Result>
    // so we can filter the results that support the limit
    // check for certain Limit Types
    public abstract Type[] AllowedLimitTypes { get; }
}

this will handle the cases where we have multiple possible limit types in our derived classes.
We can also have a convenience generic version for single limit type that is easy to override
public abstract class Result<TLimit> : Result {
    // caching
    static Type[] s_types = new Type[] { typeof(TLimit) };
    public override Type[] AllowedLimitTypes => s_types;

    // default implementation so we don't have to do it every time in our derived classes
    // sealed override doesn't allow derived classes to break the contract 
    // of having just a single limit as generic parameter 
    // (for example by including checks for multiple limits types in this method)
    // those classes should derive from the non-generic Result instead
    public sealed override bool? LimitsPassed(object limits) {
        if (limits is TLimit tLimit) return LimitsPassed(tLimit);
        return null;
    }
    public abstract bool LimitsPassed(TLimit limits);
}

public class SpecificResult : Result<SpecificLimits> {
    public double MeasureA { get; set; }
    public string MeasureB { get; set; }

    public override bool LimitsPassed(SpecificLimits limits) {
        return this.MeasureA >= limits.MeasureA_min
                && this.MeasureA <= limits.MeasureA_max
                && this.MeasureB == limits.MeasureB_master;
    }
}

For the multiple limits types we have a bit more work:
public class SpecificResult2 : Result {

    Type[] _types = new Type[] { typeof(SpecificLimits), typeof(SpecificLimits2) };
    public override Type[] AllowedLimitTypes => _types;

    public override bool? LimitsPassed(object limits) {
        return limits switch {
            SpecificLimits specLimits => LimitsPassed(specLimits),
            SpecificLimits2 specLimits2 => LimitsPassed(specLimits2),
            _ => null
        };
    }

    public bool LimitsPassed(SpecificLimits limits) {
        // implementation
        return true;
    }

    public bool LimitsPassed(SpecificLimits2 limits) {
        // implementation
        return true;
    }
}

We can also have generic convenience classes for more common cases - two or three TLimits:
public abstract class Result<TLimit1,TLimit2> 
public abstract class Result<TLimit1,TLimit2,TLimit3> 


Is there a way which doesn't allow to sneak multiple Limits types to LimitsPassed without creating generic class? I ask because my design assume that SpecificResult class will always refer to SpecificLimits. For example SpecificResultA will always refer to SpecificLimitsA, SpecificResultB to SpecificLimitsB, and so on. I am just wondering if my design is correct. For me the best approach without creating generic class is @Wyck answer, however it doesn't protect me from passing unrelated SpecificLimits class to LimitsPassed method. Thank you.

@oleq the generic Result<TLimit> is more of a convenience class which encapsulates the casting logic (from @Wyck's answer). At the same time you have what you actually want - a more derived type accepting LimitsPassed. The Types[] allows you to filter the List<Result> easily and apply the more derived functions...

also with the generic class you can filter Results List easily, i.e. is Result<SpecificLimits>

it also leaves you free to use whatever objects (including structs) for Liimts-like objects so you don't have to do pointless inheritance there as it was commented under your question.

thank you for response. I analyzed your approach and I believe it is the best implementation in my case.

The usual practice is to override the method of the base class and define another method for the specific type. Check the type of the parameter in the overriden method and pass it to the specific method for further processing.
public class SpecificResult : Result
{
    public override bool LimitsPassed(Limits limits)
        => limits is SpecificLimits specificLimits ?
           LimitsPassed(specificLimits) :
           throw new ArgumentException(); // or false

    public bool LimitsPassed(SpecificLimits limits) 
    {
        //specify parameter base type to particular type of derived class
    }
}


Another approach would be to use reflection to essentially cast the parameter from its base type to the expected derived type.  You still have to handle the case where the parameter is not the expected type though.
public class SpecificResult : Result
{
    public override bool LimitsPassed(Limits limits) {
        if (limits is SpecificLimits specificLimits) {
            // Do something with specificLimits
        } else {
            // TODO: Handle case where Limits provided are not SpecificLimits
            throw new ArgumentException("Limits must be of type SpecificLimits");
        }
    }
}


You have a couple of options. Probably you want to specify that all derived classes implementing LimitsPassed use a parameter derived from class Limits.
Example:
    public abstract class Result
    {
        public abstract bool LimitsPassed<T>(T limits) where T:Limits;
    }

    public class SpecificResult : Result
    {
        public override bool LimitsPassed<T>(T limits)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public abstract class Limits
    {

    }

    public class SpecificLimits : Limits
    {

    }

The other option is whether or not the object passed to LimitsPassed logically has a consistent contract, in which case you could take the interface-based approach.
Example:
    public abstract class Result
    {
        public abstract bool LimitsPassed(ILimits limits);
    }

    public class SpecificResult : Result
    {
        public override bool LimitsPassed(ILimits limits)
        {
            //specify parameter base type to particular type of derived class
        }
    }

    public interface ILimits
    {

    }

    public class SpecificLimits : ILimits
    {

    }


In the 2nd example it doesn't matter if it's an interface.  You could have left it as class Limits instead of interface ILimits.  The important aspect of your 2nd example is that you've modified the type of the argument to LimitsPassed to accept the same type of argument as the base class method.

@Wyck True. However, because one should preferably code to an interface over a concretion/implementation, an interface is shown here.
